# elixir Poison data type parse Json data

Tags: json, elixir

I'm new to elixir, so sorry, I'm sure this is simple.

I can find anything about a data type that follows this pattern:

`%{"quoted_string" => "string_w_quotes"}`

What is that called?

Here's the problem I'm having. I'm using HTTPoison and Poison. I call a Get request and successfully get a JSON response, then I pipe that whole response to Poison. Then I pattern match on what potion gives me. I'm trying to get to the point where I can say `body.address` but I get an error.

Here's the relevant code:

```
# after call
...
body
|> Poison.decode!
|> case do
  {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: body}} ->
    IO.puts "response received"
    body.address
...
```

Then it prints this:

> ... response received
>   ** (KeyError) key :address not found in: %{"address" => "123", "public" => "abc"} ...

So I guess my real question is how do I turn

> %{"address" => "123", "public" => "abc"}

into

> %{:address => "123", :public => "abc"}

so that I can successfully use this:

```
body.address
```

is that right?

Comment: Its a bad idea to convert strings from the internet to atoms. Atoms are not garbage collected. So, use the `body["address"]` approach you discovered below. However, to answer your question `Enum.map(params, fn {key, value} -> {String.to_atom(key), value} end) |> Enum.into(%{})`. But DON'T do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a map with a binary key.

The `body.address` is a short for accessing an atom key in a map. However, it does not work if the key is not present. Your better to use `body[:address]` which will return nil if the map does not have the key.

For binary keys, you can use `body["address"]` to access the struct. Alternative, you can use `Map.get(body, "address")`.

Comment: thanks for this info, it helped me solve a related problem too! I was able to remove the the `(keys: :atoms!)` and call it using `body["address"]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

modified code to say this:

```
    |> Poison.decode!(keys: :atoms!)
```

That told Poison I want the keys as atoms.

Comment: I'll leave my answer there since I explained the pattern and why it was failing. I don't recommend using the `.` notation to access maps unless you want it to raise an exception if the key is not present.